# Proof of the Basis Extension Theorem for modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Show that if $f: M \rightarrow F$ is an $R$-module EPImorphism onto a free module $F$ and $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ a family in $M$ whose image $f(x_i)_{i \in I}$ is a basis of $F$, then
>
> $$(1) \qquad M = \ker(f) \oplus (\bigoplus_{i \in I} Rx_i)$$
>
> Show that from this immediately follows that if $N \subseteq M$ is a free submodule such that $M/N$ is free, then each basis of $N$ can be extended to a basis of $M$. (This is the so-called Basis Extension Theorem for modules.)

I think I managed to prove $(1)$ in the following way: Let $m \in M$. We make a case distinction:

1. Case: Assume $f(m) \ne 0$. In this case we have for unique $(r_i)_{i \in I} \in R^{I}$ $f(m) = f(\sum_{i \in I} r_ix_i)$ and can thus identify the image of $m$ under $f$ with a unique sum $\sum_{i \in I} r_ix_i$, thus $f^{-1}(f(m)) \in\bigoplus_{i \in I} Rx_i$.
2. Case: Assume $f(m) = 0$. In this case we obviously have $f^{-1}(f(m)) \in \ker{(f)}$.

Is this correct? Further I do not quite see how to do the second part. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the properties of a free module, you can define a unique homomorphism $g\colon F\to M$ by declaring that $g(f(x_i))=x_i$ and therefore $f\circ g$ is the identity on $F$.

Then it's a general fact about modules that, if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a homomorphism and there exists $g\colon Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g$ is the identity, then $X\cong \ker f\oplus Y$.

Indeed you can define $\varphi\colon X\to\ker f\oplus Y$ by $\varphi(x)=(x-g(f(x)),f(x))$ and it's simple to prove it's an isomorphism:

1. if $\varphi(x)=0$, then $x=g(f(x))$ and $f(x)=0$, so $x=0$;
2. if $z\in\ker f$ and $y\in Y$, then $(z,y)=\varphi(z+g(y))$, because $z+g(y)-g(f(z+g(y))$, so $z+g(y)-g(f(g(y)))=z+g(y)-g(y)=z$, and $f(g(y))=y$.

In the case of $N$ and $M/N$ free, you can use the canonical map $f\colon M\to M/N$ and get that $M\cong \ker f\oplus (M/N)=N\oplus(M/N)$. The direct sum of free modules is free and you get a basis by putting together bases.